# New syntax of the title command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When 1.14 rolled around, I got a little smarter on commands and stuff like that, though when I looked for an updated command for the title command I only found answers from 2015. Does anybody know the updated form of the title command?

Comment: Edward, I edited your question a bit, to clarify it for others. If you'd like a different form for your question, feel free to edit or rollback it. Otherwise, I'm fairly certain the [Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/title) has updated answers.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the `/title` command in 1.14. looks like this:

```
/title <target> <actionbar|subtitles|title> <title>´

/title <target> <clear|reset>

/title <target> times <fadeIn> <stay> <fadeOut>
```